# Angular4 - Getting "undefined" instead of dropdown selected value

Tags: javascript, angular

First I should say I went through all answered which posted for similar problem, but none of them worked for me! it's really odd, since the code it seems OK, but still it always give me undefined in change event!

I tried this :

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="onCountryChange()">                            
    <option *ngFor="let x of countries" [ngValue]="x">{{x.CouName}}</option>
</select>
```

and in my component

```
 selectedCountry: any[];

 onCountryChange() {  
    console.log(this.selectedCountry);//Give me undefined      
}
```

Also I tried this :

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" (change)="onCountryChange($event.target.value)">                            
    <option *ngFor="let x of countries" [ngValue]="x">{{x.CouName}}</option>
</select>
```

this one also give me undefined

```
onCountryChange(value) {  
    console.log(value);//Give me undefined      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(ngModelChange)="onCountryChange($event)"
```

instead of

```
(change)="onCountryChange()"
```

`(change)` is fired before the `[(ngModel)]="..."` binding was updated.

Comment: I just used ngModelChange as you suggested, but still getting undefined!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Ideally you could provide a reproduction using https://stackblitz.com/ or Plunker. I added the `$event` parameter.

Comment: it's really weird! I reproduced in stackblitz and it's working fine, the same code! but in my project getting undefined! even the $event parameter is undefined! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7yniz

Comment: Interesting. One observation. `selectedCountry` should be an object (country) not an array. Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: I changed selectedCountry: any[]; to selectedCountry: Number; and change the ngValue to x.CouId which is a number, now I get the value, Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with angular.

**[`Select change event occurs before ngModel updates`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7971)**

You should change from **`(change)`** to **`(ngModelChange)`**

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="onCountryChange(selectedObj)">                            
    <option *ngFor="let x of countries" [ngValue]="x">{{x.CouName}}</option>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcq3gp4uP5RntijmQ9rI?p=preview)**